# Error creating bean with name 'clienteRestController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'clientService';

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

Error creating bean with name 'clienteRestController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'clientService'.

Error creating bean with name 'clientServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'clientDao'.

Error creating bean with name 'IClienteDao': Invocation of init method failed.

nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class java.lang.Package

I am use eclipse with spring boot project with MySQL Database, when i run the project i see this error, i see some solves in stack Overflow but not worked , can any body help, thanks

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "package")
public class Package implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

private String name;

private int count;

@Column(precision=18, scale=2) /** Number (16, 2) **/
private double price;

@Column(name = "createAt")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date createAt;


public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getCount() {
    return count;
}
public void setCount(int count) {
    this.count = count;
}
public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
}
public Date getCreateAt() {
    return createAt;
}
public void setCreateAt(Date createAt) {
    this.createAt = createAt;
}
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

}

Controller "ClienteRestController":

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"http://localhost:4200"})
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/apiHorsesClub")
public class ClienteRestController {

@Autowired
private IClienteService clientService;

@GetMapping("clients")
public List<Package> index()
{
    return clientService.findAll();
}
```

}

DAO layer "clientDao":

```
public interface IClienteDao extends CrudRepository<Package, Long>{
}
```

Service layer "IClienteService" :
    public interface IClienteService {

```
public List<Package> findAll();

}
```

implementation the service "ClientServiceImpl " :

```
@Service
public class ClientServiceImpl implements IClienteService {

@Autowired
private IClienteDao clientDao;

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<Package> findAll() {
    return (List<Package>) clientDao.findAll();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all, i resolved the problem.
the problem in name of the entity "Package", its reserved in Java